# NSFetchedResultsController's sectioninfo seems to persist even with FRC set to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a head view (View A) with a segmented control. Segment 0 loads a FRC, and sets the sectionnamekeypath from a non-transient property and sorts on it.

Segment 1 loads a FRC, sets the sectionNameKeyPath from a transient property (month and year as in Apple's example pretty much) and sorts on the same non-transient property segment 0 does.

When a cell of Segment 0's FRC is clicked, it pushes to View B, here a new FRC loads selection-specific objects using a predicate. It sets its sectionNameKeyPath from a second transient property and sorts on the same non-transient property the other 2 do.

The following is what happens:

1. View A:

   Switch between Segment 0 and 1 multiple times. The FRCs load what they're supposed to.

   Select a cell in segment 0 --> this correctly pushes View B
2. View B:

   The FRC loads as intended.

   Press the back button --> the view correctly dismissed back to view A.
3. View A:

   Segment 0 and its FRC are correctly loaded and shown

   ```
   Select segment 1: Error:

   "has an out of order section name **segment name from View B's section**"
   ```

I find it very weird that the error it gives, contains the sectionname from the FRC on the previous view. I set the FRC and its delegate to nil when the view WillDisAppear.

When I Breakpoint the transient properties, I can see that it only requests segment 1's FRC so it doesn't seem to make sense that it can still see View B's sections?

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be because you are using same cache for both the `NSFetchedResultsController` instances. Pass different cache names when creating instance,

```
_fetchController = [[KREFetchedResultController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                       managedObjectContext:context
                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionKey"
                                                                  cacheName:@"mycache"];
```

You can also delete the cache when not required by calling `NSFetchedResultsController`'s class method `deleteCacheWithName:` to delete particular cache containing cached section information,

```
/* Deletes the cached section information with the given name.
    If name is nil, then all caches are deleted.
*/
+ (void)deleteCacheWithName:(NSString *)name;
```

Or pass `nil` to delete all caches.

If you do not wish to cache then pass cache name as `nil` when creating fetched results controller.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Amar, but I already had all three FRCs with a cache of nil because it acts up sometimes. Weird thing is, I tried setting View B's cache and it only crashed one time, after that it works again. (Apart from the cached one not updating of course) Perhaps I should give them all a cache and delete that every time a new view is pushed? Or ontain that FRC to only that view in some way..

Comment: If I change FRC 1's sectionNameKeyPath to the same transient property as View B's FRC then this crash does not happen. So something seems to go wrong with the sections because these FRCs get data from the same entity but with different sections? I set everything to nil when passing to views so I don't understand why one can still hinder the other :/

Answer (score 0):

- List item

I think I solved it.. Breakpointed nearly every line of code but that got me nowhere. The caching seperately did not solve it.

I set my controllers and their delegates to nil in the last lines of the prepareforsegue method. I moved that code to reside within the specific segue's if method

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueID"]) {

//set destination VC's properties first since they might come from the FRC.

 _fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
 _fetchedResultsController = nil;
}
```

and it suddenly works.. Very strange, I thought it would get executed either way, either in the viewDidUnload, or at the end of the prepareForSegue. For some reason these FRC delegates are very persistent across viewcontrollers.

Update:

I made a typo in my transientproperty as well. Pretty sure that was it. The PrimitiveProperty1 was being set with Transient property 1 and 2 ... Auto-complete filled it in I guess :)